# getRef(position).getKey() in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android

In FirebaseRecyclerAdapter I can use the `getRef(position).getKey()` but I am using a RecyclerView.Adapter and I want get the key whenever the user click the checkbox. Here is my code in onBindViewHolder():

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolders holder, final int position) {
    holder.setName(mUserNameList.get(position));
    holder.setDesc(mUserDescList.get(position));
    holder.setImage(mUserPicList.get(position));
    holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            //TODO: get the key

        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible to get the key in RecyclerView.Adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solved my own question just by reconstructing my code.

**1. In the adapter class, I created an interface for itemClickListener**

```
public interface RecyclerViewItemClick {

    public void OnItemClickListener(UsersViewHolders holder, int position);

}
```

**and create a global**

```
private RecyclerViewItemClick mListener;
```

**add it to constructor**

```
public MessageListAdapter(RecyclerViewItemClick listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}
```

**2. In onBindViewHolder() I passed the holder and the position**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UsersViewHolders holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mListener.OnItemClickListener(holder, position);

        }

    });
}
```

**3. In your activity, add this code. Declare a global variable for ArrayList to store the keys and call the addListenerForSingleValueEvent to your DatabaseReference**

```
//mUserDatabase is a DatabaseReference
mUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String uid = datas.getKey();

                //mUserKey is an ArrayList<String>
                mUserKey.add(uid);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**4. Now add this to get the key for every position**

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(new MyAdapter.RecyclerViewItemClick() {

        @Override
        public void OnItemClickListener(PickMemberAdapter.UsersViewHolders holder, int position) {

            String userKey = mUserKey.get(position);

            if (!holder.mCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, userKey, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, userKey, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    });
```